AC thermostat and outside compressor seem to work, but no air coming out of vents
The other day our AC stopped working.  It is one of two split units, with standard outdoor condenser and indoor fan in the attic.  The thermostat seems to work, and by work, I mean shows what the current temp in the house is and seems to turn on the outdoor unit when the temp is above the desired temp.  The outdoor unit seems to work in that it turns on and blows air.  It is the indoor (attic) fan that doesn't seem to come on, and as a result, we don't get any air out of the vents.  The outdoor unit doesn't seem to blow hot air like out other one (instead, just normal temp air), but that is not surprising, given my rudimentary understanding of how ACs work and that the indoor unit doesn't seem to be on.
Are there things I should look for to see if it is something simple I can fix?  I already checked the circuit breakers in the basement.
Here is the attic unit:

And here is the outdoor unit:


lost coolant liquid

That would explain why non-cool air would come out of the vents, but would it explain why the indoor blower isn't running at all?  I wouldn't think so, would it?

either the blower failed or some component that makes the blower turns on has failed.  Make sure the cover is on the air handler, there is usually a switch that turns off the blower if you open it.

The outdoor unit doesn't blow air (into the house).  If the fan runs, it's only to circulate air over the condenser coil.  If the air handler blower isn't working, that is a separate issue.  Check the transformer in the air handler to see if it's outputting the proper (or any) voltage.

Some Air handler units have a seperate  low voltage fuse to protect the fan operation.  Sometimes the fan will not come on if the drain line is clogged. ( there is a safety switch  in an attachment to the drain line.)   The drain line would need to be unclogged.  In some odd instances the system need to be shut down for about 10 minutes for a system reset. ( Air handler and compressor breakers off)  Then when the breakers are turned back on the unit may work.  However this is temporary and you need professional diagnosis of the problem.
